# Java interoperability: how to declare a compile-time array constant in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I’ve got this [Java annotation declaration](https://github.com/cbeust/jcommander/blob/master/src/main/java/com/beust/jcommander/Parameter.java) and want to use it in Kotlin

```
class CurlCommand {
    Parameter(names = "-groups", description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
    var groups: Array<String>? = null
}
```

The compiler reports *TYPE_MISMATCH*
   Required: kotlin.Array<kotlin.String>
   Found: kotlin.String

I’ve tried

```
Parameter(names = Array<String>(1, {i-> "-groups"}), description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
var groups: Array<String>? = null
```

and got *“Error:(20, 23) Kotlin: An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant”*

How can I satisfy the Kotlin compiler?

Java simply accepts

```
@Parameter(names = "-groups", description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
public String groups;
```

Answer (score 6):

You declare a constant in Kotlin like so:

```
const val LG_PACKAGE = "com.myapp"
```

However, the [kotlin documentation for compile-time constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants) says that they can only be of type String or a primitive type. So the closest you can get if you want to use constants is this:

```
const val LG_PACKAGE = "com.myapp"

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf(LG_PACKAGE))
@EntityScan(basePackages = arrayOf(LG_PACKAGE))
open class LgApp {
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the answer is very simple, once one discovers it accidently

```
array("-groups")
```

Although the Kotlin converter gave me this code

```
@Parameter(names = "-groups", description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
public String groups;
```

as I’ve mentioned above.

Comment: Java seems to treat arrays in annotations as varargs so that you can omit the curly braces for single values. Kotlin does not. As it seems, some recent progress has been made in that regard, though: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2576#tab=History